# Filter a model in Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a project model with a name:string and state:integer. There are 5 types of states. For example I want to put all projects with state 3 into the #prospects div. How can I make this work?

```
appendProject: (project) =>
  # this renders all projects
  view = new Trackproject.Views.Project(model: project)
  @$('#projects').append(view.render().el)
  # this is how i want it to work
  @$('#prospects').append(state3.render().el)
  @$('#upcoming').append(state4.render().el)
```

I think you can filter it in the collection file but I can't figure out how to load it into the views.

I work with Rails, Backbone and Coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer is

```
  appendProject: (project) =>
    view = new Trackproject.Views.Project(
      model: project
    )
    state = project.get("state")
    if state is 1
      @$("#projects").append view.render().el
    else if state is 2
      @$("#prospects").append view.render().el
    else if state is 3
      @$("#upcoming").append view.render().el
    else if state is 4
      @$("#current").append view.render().el
    else if state is 5
      @$("#completed").append view.render().el
    else
      @$("#projects").append view.render().el
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.each(projectCollection.where({state: 3}), function(project) {
    $('#prospects').append($('<span>' + project.get('name') + '</span>'));
});
```

Comment: I see but where do I put that piece of code? In the collection or the view?

Comment: In the view. And you need to have projects collection in the view of course.